# Closed form of the sum of a fast-converging series

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions

The chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is
$$
f(x)\, dx = \frac1{\Gamma(k/2)} \left( \frac x2\right)^{(k/2)-1} e^{-x/2} \left( \frac{dx} 2 \right) \qquad \text{for } x>0.
$$
This function, without the $\text{“} dx \text{”}$ and with $k=4.3,$ and multiplied by units of temperature, was used to model the amount by which the temperature of a metal object exceeded the ambient temperature at time $x$ when something that happened at time $0$ caused its temperature to rise. (This was in some industrial process involving welding, and I don't know much about the specifics.)

The engineer who did this wanted to look at $$ \sum_{j\,=\,-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x +2.3j) $$ (recall that $k=4.3$). Clearly this series converges fairly fast to a periodic function. About four or five terms is enough to give and impression of its appearance.

Does this have a closed form?

Can anything of interest be said about it beyond what appears here?

Comment: It has closed form in terms of Lerch transcendent.

Comment: @Nemo Can you elaborate on that in an answer?